# collection in collection in list should be displayed alongside data in list

Tags: c#, list

So i have a list with data, in that list there's a collection and in that collection there is another collection.

the tricky part is that this last collection should be displayed alongside the first list.

to make an example of this the list contains a name a collection of houses and some more info. the collection of houses has a name and a collection of rooms.
and finally the collection of rooms has a name.

Now i want to print a table like this;

house

roomname name

roomname name
..

house

.
.
.

with just foreach and select statements i feel like this won't work and i can't change the data structure so i'm stuck with this.

```
private byte[] CreateReport(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, List<TotalData> data)
    {
        var reportingHelper = new ReportingHelper();
        reportingHelper.WriteRow("Period", fromDate.ToShortDateString(), toDate.ToShortDateString());
        reportingHelper.InsertEmptyLine();

        foreach (var GroupedByDate in data.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Date).OrderBy(x => x.Key))
        {
            reportingHelper.WriteRow(ordersGroupedByDate.Key.ToShortDateString());
            reportingHelper.WriteHeader(null, "House", "Room", "Name");
            foreach (var grouped in GroupedByDate)
            {
                foreach (var House in  grouped.house)
                {
                    reportingHelper.WriteRow(null,House.housename);
                    foreach (var room in House.rooms)
                    {
                        reportingHelper.WriteRow(null,null,room.name, GroupedByDate.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return reportingHelper.ToArray();
    }
```

this is what i have at the moment.

Comment: First it would help if you could show the code that defines your collections.  Second showing an attempt at solving this.  And finally describe what you mean by "print a table".  Do you mean you are printing to a file or to the console, or do you mean you want to save it in a DB?

Comment: i'm printing it to an excel file but that part is already working. i'll add the code that i have in edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ :

```
var result = lstHouses.Select(h => new {h.Name, h.Rooms.SelectMany(r => r.Name)} );
```

This way, you'll have as output a `IEnumerable<string, IEnumerable<string>>` with the House name as key and a list of Rooms' names as values.

You can remove the `.Name` to directly have objects too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Linq*, e.g.:

```
  List<House> houses = new List<House>();
  ...

  var lines = houses  
    .SelectMany(house => new String[] {house.Name}
      .Concat(house.Rooms.Select(room => room.Name)));

  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```